# Custom pooling layer - minmax pooling - Keras - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, max-pooling

I want to define my custom pooling layer, instead of returning the max values like the MaxPooling layer, it would output the k maximum values and the k minimum values.

I am using Tensorflow as the backend.
I need the output vector to be sorted.

I was thinking about doing that:

```
from keras.layers.pooling import _Pooling1D

class MinMaxPooling1D(_Pooling1D):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MinMaxPooling1D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _pooling_function(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        sorted_ = tf.contrib.framework.sort(inputs, axis = -1)
        print(sorted_)
        return np.concatenate((sorted_[:,:,:self.output_dim/2], sorted_[:,:,-self.output_dim/2:]))
```

But then I get:

```
Tensor("min_max_pooling1d_1/sort/Neg_1:0", shape=(?, 1, 1, ?), dtype=float32)
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

The MinMaxPooling1D layer is applied to a (None, 1, 10) shape output.

I was then thinking about adding a Flatten layer before the MinMaxPooling1D one, but then there is a dimension issue:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer min_max_pooling1d_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a Pooling Layer, I am using a Lambda:

```
def top_k(inputs, k):
  return tf.nn.top_k(inputs, k=k, sorted=True).values

def least_k(inputs, k):
    return -tf.nn.top_k(-inputs, k=k, sorted = True).values

def minmax_k(inputs, k):
    return tf.concat([least_k(inputs, k), top_k(inputs, k)], axis = -1)

model = Sequential()
...
model.add(Lambda(minmax_k, arguments={'k': R}))
```

Answer (score 5):

So what you want to build is a Keras Layer that will take 3D input of shape `[batch_dim, pool_dim, channels]` and produce 4D output `[batch_dim, pool_dim, channels, min_max_channels]`.

Unlike Keras `_Pooling1D` you will actually change the number of dimensions, and I would recommend to implement your layer by inheriting directly from keras `Layer`.

Implement the `call` method using `tf.sort` and taking the desired amount of max and min elements from the sorted input, and concatenating them along a new dimension (consider using `tf.expand_dims` and `tf.concat`).

p.s. I have tried to implement this myself, and have discovered it to be complicated. You basicly want something different from maxpool, and slightly more. You might take a look at `tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py` method `max_pool` to appreciate what kind of work you are in for, unless you can find some ready implementation somewhere...